# Running NodeTool flush on different node in a Cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

SO assume I have 2 nodes in a Cassandra Cluster
10.199.199.1
10.199.199.2

Now I am on 10.199.199.1

and I want to flush my other node(10.199.199.2) using nodetool flush

I have tried running this on node (10.199.199.1)

```
bin/nodetool -h 10.199.199.2 flush
```

but it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '10.199.199.2:7199' - NoSuchObjectException: 'no such object in table'.
```

Can anyone help me in this?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the answer of your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a misconfiguration problem. I tried doing the same and it worked for me.

Cassandra only listens on localhost by default. Check the conf/cassandra-env.sh file and make sure that JMX is configured properly.

If this does not work for you, try adding java.rmi.server.logCalls=true in the cassandra-env.sh to get some more information for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Changes in cassandra-env.sh are necessary for each host with the error message: 
"Failed to connect to ':7199' " in order to work.

Set for all servers in Cassandra cluster instead  the proper IP address or host name:
...
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname="
...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the node on which I tried to connect declares this line on its `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1 <hostname>
```

Remove this line and restart cassandra on this node, and it should work.

More reference:

- https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html#standard-jmx-auth
- https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-trblshoot/doc/troubleshooting/connectionsFail.html
- https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/faq/index.html?highlight=jmx#nodetool-says-connection-refused-to-host-127-0-1-1-for-any-remote-host-what-gives